# How to create an alias for a database in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alias

How can I create a short alias name for a database?

I have a database that for use with an application has a very long name. I'm writing queries on the database in SQL Server and don't want to have to type out the long name.

I'd like to have

```
SELECT * FROM shrt_name.dbo.table_name
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM garbase_long_db_name_rqrd_for_compatibility_reasons.dbo.tablename.
```

I'm aware of synonym for tables, but I need the whole db not each table.

Comment: Another person had the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722066/how-to-create-an-alias-of-database-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a linked server referring to the database locally by specifying the database as default. Also, you can use `USE` statement in order to ignore fully qualifying your tables.