# Coldfusion ORM Entity: Link to a table on another database?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Is it possible to have the table property of an ORM entity to be a table on another database, like this: `component persistent="true" table="anotherdb..tableonanotherdb"`. I got a table undefined error when I tried it.

If not, what are my options if the app needs to be able to update anotherdb..tableonanotherdb, instead of just viewing it (which I can simply set up a view for)?

I'm on CF10.

Comment: What DBMS (database platform) are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: CF10 supports multiple datasources for ORM, using the `this.datasource` setting in Application.cfc. CF will run separate Hibernate sessions for each datasource. So unless you need the entity in your second database to be directly related to an entity in your primary database, just use a separate datasource. For more info, see https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Support+for+multiple+data+sources+for+ORM in the ColdFusion docs.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten yeah unfortunately the entities from the 2 databases do relate. I think we'll probably have to rethink the overall design here a bit. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I wonder if a Synonym would work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722066/how-to-create-an-alias-of-database-in-sql-server

Comment: @JamesAMohler Just tried that, unfortunately didn't work.