# How to shorten or alias database names in your query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I have ten to twenty databases in my server. Everytime  i need to query i want to put something like this

```
Select *  from otp-devices.dbo.deviceid 
select module from mr1ghp/security.dbo.alarmmodlink
```

Our database names are  long . Is it possible to shorten or alias  database name in query  `otp-devices` `mr1ghp/security`

Comment: I don't understand your question.  First, `otp-devices.dbo.deviceid` is not a valid name for a database.  It comes close to a table reference (but the hyphen is incorrect).  What is your issue?  Lots of databases or lots of tables?

Comment: @GordonLinoff . dbo is schema and deviceid is table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ,  updated the question

Comment: There is no straight forward way to do this. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722066/how-to-create-an-alias-of-database-in-sql-server)

Comment: @CodingYoshi . not the one i am looking for.

Comment: Do you need three part names anyway? Unless you are performing cross database queries just `USE YourDb` and use two part names.

Comment: i mostly use cross queries and often my queries end up as long

Comment: @MartinSmith ........

Answer (score 2):

You can make an alias with the keyword **AS** like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `otp-devices.dbo.deviceid ` AS otp
```

Comment: This is true for one query. but I have seen a way to do it from the database level itself. that is we can use that name for our database name in anywhere in our sql server.

Comment: @coffemug there isn’t anything like that in SQL Server. Except possibly sqlcmd variables.

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL Server 2008, SQL Server has supported synonyms.

You can read about the syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql).

You can read about the ideas [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/synonyms-database-engine).

I'm not really a fan of synonyms.  I find databases harder to navigate when the same object has different names in different places -- and I cannot readily see the mapping (as with aliases in a single query).

Comment: Synonyms are not supported for database names

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . But they are supported for table names, so that might still help the OP, sort of.

Comment: @GordonLinoff .  yes

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to use views to provide the link to tables in other databases. Use naming conventions to identify which database the view is linked to. This also helps to insulate the code from any changes to database names.

```
CREATE VIEW vOD_deviceid AS SELECT * FROM [otp-devices].dbo.deviceid ;
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW vSC_alarmmodlink AS SELECT * FROM mr1ghp/security.dbo.alarmmodlink
```

Then elsewhere

```
SELECT * FROM vOD_deviceid; -- OD prefix identifies the database
SELECT module FROM vSC_alarmmodlink;
```

Just substitute the view name wherever you would have used the full database.schema.tablename.

Comment: This can be done for repetitive queries, and  i do have some views for the purpose but most of the time  our requirement changes and we dont have a particular query for our purpose

Comment: I mean that once you have defined the baseline view of the table, then you always use the view instead of referring directly to the table - even in other views. So the view is the single local representation of the table in the other database. You don't create a different view for every query you have, that would defeat the objective.